# Can't install MySQL 5.5.11.7 (beta)

Tags: installation, mysql, windows-installer

I've downloaded MySQL 5.5.11.7 installer from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/. When launching the installer I get the following error message:

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Here's a link to the download: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-installer-for-windows.html?download=1.

My operating system is Windows 7.

**edit**

When launching the windows installer installer as suggested by one user I receive an error message that says it "is not a valid Win32 application". What to do?

**/edit**

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted download.  Try downloading it again.  Second...it's in beta, so they might be working out some bugs and not checking their release files.

Comment: @aking: Thanks, but I've tried downloading it more than once. Also, I know of someone who has installed it successfully.

Comment: okay so now it's not just the mysql installer, but the microsoft windows installer too?  sounds like a failing hard drive or rootkit.  check disk for errors, sfc /scannow, run AV on hard disk slaved into another PC.  when it's not just mysql that completely changes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the latest version of Windows Installer from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=889482fc-5f56-4a38-b838-de776fd4138c&DisplayLang=en

Comment: I've downloaded it. When launching I receive an error message that says it "is not a valid Win32 application". What to do?

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion.  it didn't solve, but it did shed light on the REAL problem

Comment: Try running sfc /scannow in an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Could you please explain yourself in more details? I have no idea what you've said.

Comment: You may have some corrupt system files. Running the System File Checker may resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that message before.

Chances are very good that the downloaded file became corrupted. Remove it from your system and re-download it again.